# Modify values in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping, reduce

I have an array of objects and I would like to modify them based on a "type" value using another array of objects. I get a big list of objects but I am supposed to get only 2.

This is what I have:

```js
const convertData = (type, value) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "date":
      {
        return new Date(Number(value)).toDateString();
      }
    case "currency":
      {
        return value ? `$${value}` : null;
      }
    default:
      return value;
  }
};

const headers = [{
  field: 'amount',
  type: 'currency'
}, {
  field: 'deliveredDate',
  type: 'date'
}]

const body = [{
  id: 1,
  amount: 4000,
  deliveredDate: "1610427600000"
}, {
  id: 2,
  amount: 6000,
  deliveredDate: "1611118800000"
}]

const result = body.map(i => {
  const keys = Object.keys(i);
  return keys.map(k => {
    return {
      ...i,
      [k]: headers.find(i => i.field === k) ? convertData(headers.find(i => i.field === k).type, i[k]) : null
    }
  })
})

console.log(result.flat())


/**
Expected Result
[{
  id: 1,
  amount: $4000,
  deliveredDate: "Tue Jan 12 2021"
}, {
  id: 2,
  amount: $6000,
  deliveredDate: "Wed Jan 20 2021"
}]
*/
```

The field value in headers represents the key in the body array. And the value in the corresponding body object needs to be changed as per the type in the header object. Please advise.

Comment: Please don't ping users like that.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach, which also allows flexible adaption and code-reuse, takes advantage of the so often overlooked optional second argument, one is allowed to provide to most array methods ... [`thisArg` for e.g. `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax).

Thus, such an approach does create a *lookup table* from the OP's `headers` list and does provide it to the mapping process since one does not want to search (within each iteration step of `map`) always again and again the same list in order to find the correct/matching related conversion `type`.

The actual mapping then will be easy. Implement a function which assumes its `this` context to be a *lookup table* and which does (re)create a type-converted version of the provided (here currently processed) object by looking up the correct conversion `type` before providing it to the OP's `convertData` function.

```js
const convertData = (type, value) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "date": {
      return new Date(Number(value)).toDateString();
    }
    case "currency": {
      return value ? `$${value}` : null;
    }
    default:
      return value;
  }
};

const headers = [{
  field: 'amount',
  type: 'currency'
}, {
  field: 'deliveredDate',
  type: 'date'
}];

const body = [{
  id: 1,
  amount: 4000,
  deliveredDate: "1610427600000"
}, {
  id: 2,
  amount: 6000,
  deliveredDate: "1611118800000"
}];

function createConversionTypeLookupTable(conversionTypeList) {
  return conversionTypeList.reduce((table, conversionTypeItem) => {

    table[conversionTypeItem.field] = conversionTypeItem.type;
    return table;

  }, {});
}

function createConvertedItemViaBoundLookupTable(item) {
  const lookupTable = (this || {}); // more fail safe.
  return Object.entries(item).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {

    obj[key] = convertData((lookupTable[key] || key), value);
    return obj;

  }, {});
}

console.log(
  'Converted Item List ...',
  body.map(
    createConvertedItemViaBoundLookupTable,
    createConversionTypeLookupTable(headers)
  )
);
console.log(
  'Conversion Type Lookup Table ...',
  createConversionTypeLookupTable(headers)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @a2441918 ... are there any questions regarding the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `map` twice, once on the array and again on the keys, hence you get more than the items in array, and the objects are not correct since you are calling `convertData` on different objects each time

Consider doing it as below -

```js
const convertData = (type, value) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "date":
      {
        return new Date(Number(value)).toDateString();
      }
    case "currency":
      {
        return value ? `$${value}` : null;
      }
    default:
      return value;
  }
};

const headers = [{
  field: 'amount',
  type: 'currency'
}, {
  field: 'deliveredDate',
  type: 'date'
}]

const body = [{
  id: 1,
  amount: 4000,
  deliveredDate: "1610427600000"
}, {
  id: 2,
  amount: 6000,
  deliveredDate: "1611118800000"
}]

const result = body.map(i => {
  const newItem = {};
  for (const prop in i) {
    const header = headers.find(f => f.field === prop);
    const value = i[prop];
    newItem[prop] = header ? convertData(header.type, value) : value
  }
  return newItem;
});

console.log(result)
```

---

### EDIT 1:

```js
const convertData = (type, value) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "date":
      {
        return new Date(Number(value)).toDateString();
      }
    case "currency":
      {
        return value ? `$${value}` : null;
      }
    default:
      return value;
  }
};

const headers = [{
  field: 'amount',
  type: 'currency'
}, {
  field: 'deliveredDate',
  type: 'date'
}]

const body = [{
  id: 1,
  amount: 4000,
  deliveredDate: "1610427600000"
}, {
  id: 2,
  amount: 6000,
  deliveredDate: "1611118800000"
}]

const result = body.map(i => {
  const newItem = {};
  var keys = Object.keys(i);
  keys.forEach((prop) => {
    const header = headers.find(f => f.field === prop);
    const value = i[prop];
    newItem[prop] = header ? convertData(header.type, value) : value
  });
  return newItem;
});

console.log(result);
```

---

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil. Is there a way to use without for of.. My IDE throws an error to use guard in.

Comment: @a2441918, Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` with a replacer function does what the OP is looking for.

```js
// OP code and data
//
const convertData = (type, value) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "date":
      {
        return new Date(Number(value)).toDateString();
      }
    case "currency":
      {
        return value ? `$${value}` : null;
      }
    default:
      return value;
  }
};

const headers = [{
  field: 'amount',
  type: 'currency'
}, {
  field: 'deliveredDate',
  type: 'date'
}]

const body = [{
  id: 1,
  amount: 4000,
  deliveredDate: "1610427600000"
}, {
  id: 2,
  amount: 6000,
  deliveredDate: "1611118800000"
}]

// use the OP code to convert a value to a string formatted by its key
//
const convertField = (key, value) => {
  let header = headers.find(e => e.field === key)
  return header ? convertData(header.type, value) : value
}

const convertedStr = JSON.stringify(body, convertField);
const convertedObj = JSON.parse(convertedStr);
console.log(convertedObj);
```

Comment: This approach not only iterates 2 times due to a full stringify/parse cycle, it in addition iterates the `headers` array for every single item-stringification step again and again. Its usage also is limited to just valid JSON data and allows not for other data structures than that.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, I think you're right: my answer depends on valid JS objects as input and runs in linear time. Do let me know if you find a solution that runs in sub-linear time or handles ill-formed inputs. ;-)

Comment: 1/2 There is a difference in between valid JSON data and valid JS objects ... not every perfectly valid JS object can be directly mapped into a valid JSON structure. You might also think about the implementation of both `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`; any implementation will somehow feature loops within loops and/or recursion. One definitely pays a bigger toll on using the former than with iterating exactly twice ... one array via `reduce` in order to create a lookup table and finally the original array via `map`.

Comment: 2/2 And even though the Q. was not about performance and the above solution works as intended I thought it will be helpful to the OP to have pointed the possible limitations of it (especially using `find` instead of a property lookup within every converter step).